# Mazda 626 1995 automatic won't shift gears

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, mazda-626

I have a 1995 Mazda 626, 2.0L, automatic transmission.

The transmission won't shift. It stays in 3rd gear and won't go into any other gear. The car does drive, but won't change gear out of 3rd.

The car starts in 3rd gear and stops in 3rd. Reverse gear does work properly.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Check the fluid level and condition when the transmission is hot and in park. You should probably take it somewhere to get the codes pulled from the transmission controller. Though most likely if it's not a fluid issue you're going to need a new transmission.

Comment: This site specializes in those carshttp://mazda626.net/forum/5-1993-2002-2l-i4/

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes http://mazda626.net/forum/5-1993-2002-2l-i4/ clickable link if you're feeling lazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it electric shift .if do brain box controls shift of gears .if it is it's went bad.dhould not start any time unless park or neutral got a neutral switch to tell computer when it's in park and neutral. If it's not electric shift I'd say torque converter or pressure shifting selinoid inside .did it do it all at once or when you turned it off started back.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a temperature sensor(Torque converter is locked when cold) or a transmission shift solenoid(No pressure to shift to higher gear).